# Parallelizing with itertools and numba

Tags: python, loops, python-itertools, numba

I've been working on a project for a while now that requires calculating some very large datasets, and very quickly have moved beyond anything that my meager Excel knowledge could handle.  In the last few days I've started learning Python, which has helped with handling the size of data I'm dealing with, but the estimated processing time for these datasets is looking to be incredibly long (possibly a couple hundred years on my laptop).

The bottleneck here is an equation that could produce trillions or quadrillions of results, since it is calculating every combination of 6 different lists and running it through an equation that you'll see in the code.  The code works just fine, as is, but is isn't feasible for larger datasets than the example I included.  A real dataset would be something more like Set1S, 2S, and 3S being 50 items each, and Sets12A...being about 2500 items each (50x50 in this case.  These sets always have a length equal to the square of the first 3 lists, but I'm keeping things short and simple here.).

I'm well aware that the amount of results is absolutely huge, but want to start with as large a dataset as I can, so I can see how much I can reduce the input sizes without greatly impacting the results when I plot a cumulative% histogram.

```
'Calculator'
import numpy as np
Set1S = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
Set2S = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
Set3S = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
Set12A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
Set23A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
Set13A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
'Define an empty array to add results'
BlockVol = []
from itertools import product 
'itertools iterates through all combinations of lists'
for i,j,k,a,b,c in product(Set1S, Set2S, Set3S, Set12A, Set23A, Set13A):
    'This is the bottleneck equation, with large input datasets'
    BlockVol.append((abs(i*j*k*np.sin(a)*np.sin(b)*np.sin(c))))
arr = np.array(BlockVol)
'manipulate the result list a couple ways'
BlockVol = np.cbrt(BlockVol)
BlockVol = BlockVol*12
'quick check to size of results list'
len(BlockVol)
```

This took me about 3 minutes or so for 11.3M results, just from eyeballing the clock.

I've learned about @njit, prange  in the last day or so, but am a bit stuck in trying to translate my work into this format.  I do have a desktop PC with a pretty good GPU, so I think I could speed things up by a lot.  I'm well aware that the code below is a big garbage fire that doesn't do anything, but I'm hoping that I'm at least getting the point across on what I'm trying to do.

It seems that the way to go is to define a function with my 6 input lists, but i'm just not sure how to fuse the itertools product and the njit together.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
from numba import njit, prange

@njit(parallel = True)
def BlockVolCalc(Set1S, Set2S, Set3S, Set12A, Set23A, Set13A):
    numRows =Len(Set12A)
    BlockVol = np.zeros(numRows)
    for i,j,k,a,b,c in product(Set1S, Set2S, Set3S, Set12A, Set23A, Set13A):
        BlockVol.append((abs(i*j*k*np.sin(a)*np.sin(b)*np.sin(c))))
arr = np.array(BlockVol)
BlockVol = np.cbrt(BlockVol)
BlockVol = BlockVol*12
len(BlockVol)
```

Any help is much appreciated, as this is all very new and overwhelming.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved your task just by NumPy code, it is always nicer to use just NumPy instead of heavy Numba if possible. Next NumPy-only code will be as fast as same solution using Numba.

My code is `2800` times faster than your reference code, time is measured at the end of code.

In next code `BlockValCalcRef(...)` function is just your reference code organized as function. And `BlockVolCalc(...)` is my NumPy based function that should give a lot of speedup. At the end I do assert `np.allclose(...)` in order to check that both solutions give same results.

Also I simplified a bit sets creation to use one `N` param to generate sets, in your real world you just provide necessary sets.

In order to solve task I did several things:

1. Instead of computing `np.sin(...)` many times for same values I precomputed them just once for `Set12A, Set23A, Set13A`. Also precomputed `np.abs(...)` for all sets.
2. In order to compute cross-product I used special way of numpy arrays indexing like `[None, None, :, None, None, None]` this allows us to use so-called popular [numpy arrays broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

I have also idea how to improve code even more, to make it around `6` times even faster, but I think even with current huge speed you'll fill whole RAM of your machine in matter of seconds. The idea how to improve is next, currently cross product computes on each step product of `6` numbers, instead of this one can compute product of `K - 1` sets and then multiply this array by `K-th` set in order to get `K` sets product. This will give `6` time more speedup (because there are `6` sets) because you'll need just one multiplication instead of `6`.

**Update**: I've implemented second improved version of function `BlockVolCalc2(...)` according to paragraph above. It has `2800x` speedup, for larger `N` it will be probably even more faster.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3ZZPb5swFMDvfIon7VCTuVkwkyZF2mHreT0s1S5RDgacjobYlm2iRVM/e/bAQEIaWJvd5gOY988/P/u9RO/dTyXjwyHfamUcyHKr98AtSE3B5VsRBPfwGT4FwUK4aIFTqafccPkoSEThHt5DFFY6NqKLR3QR@zISNB5RRoPKIBNr@FqodPODF3e8SL@LNan5KdSo9Sv2LwTw0ti/MWw4DwCHj6AKXGW5qiVro7aQO2GcUoWFJmfaqKxMHXgTZSCnT3RDOU1oCrls9VcQnFJMudZCZoTwxJJ88jTZTHDvNpeEh@0s6WZpiKOOYYQrjfR5MnxP2nhee5IqVafqCsoLHs3BIGmtDOnJJ@t/xouwi/JyiWOgZmPeLDyGOMrR7aK8Iu3lgnTJremWc7w5Soqh5wompw5ssfS6@Ssd4tZh0O3MATe4fBl5PsYUX/Lo@Z2vMeLR@Pk7H04N34mCDNwX9l9fmKp0fURMiSXYY9A@c3stvHRdKO5iFnalb6uCN2InjBUZWb4hN6uTmm@WJXZ5PLxa2N68Vf9UmntdWQTBO7htBjwI63L5CHfKGJE63IIFLjN4wMYO3wS3panUrb0/YZfg0lXrn1YPEtZCPkPhv7RUGrjZWdxbcEmgkcCR9U3Crai18NuoEvucm1H4GD6DFekNtvTLVFFHdUX3Clw0RoTd3aidyPpUUUdFwWohslIfieEDVAYsfP41zMzOmNkbodlroFmfmv2NmnXUHtJaUf0bwMooirRQVhCO58Hxx3VIhUVwOPwB)

```
import numpy as np, time

N = 7

Set1S = np.arange(1, N + 1)
Set2S = np.arange(1, N + 1)
Set3S = np.arange(1, N + 1)
Set12A = np.arange(1, N + 1)
Set23A = np.arange(1, N + 1)
Set13A = np.arange(1, N + 1)

def BlockValCalcRef(Set1S, Set2S, Set3S, Set12A, Set23A, Set13A):
    BlockVol = []
    from itertools import product 
    for i,j,k,a,b,c in product(Set1S, Set2S, Set3S, Set12A, Set23A, Set13A):
        BlockVol.append((abs(i*j*k*np.sin(a)*np.sin(b)*np.sin(c))))
    return np.array(BlockVol)
    
def BlockVolCalc(Set1S, Set2S, Set3S, Set12A, Set23A, Set13A):
    Set1S, Set2S, Set3S = np.abs(Set1S), np.abs(Set2S), np.abs(Set3S)
    Set12A, Set23A, Set13A = np.abs(np.sin(Set12A)), np.abs(np.sin(Set23A)), np.abs(np.sin(Set13A))
    return (
        Set1S[:, None, None, None, None, None] *
        Set2S[None, :, None, None, None, None] *
        Set3S[None, None, :, None, None, None] *
        Set12A[None, None, None, :, None, None] *
        Set23A[None, None, None, None, :, None] *
        Set13A[None, None, None, None, None, :]
    ).ravel()
    
def BlockVolCalc2(Set1S, Set2S, Set3S, Set12A, Set23A, Set13A):
    Set1S, Set2S, Set3S = np.abs(Set1S), np.abs(Set2S), np.abs(Set3S)
    Set12A, Set23A, Set13A = np.abs(np.sin(Set12A)), np.abs(np.sin(Set23A)), np.abs(np.sin(Set13A))
    prod = np.ones((1,), dtype = np.float32)
    for s in reversed([Set1S, Set2S, Set3S, Set12A, Set23A, Set13A]):
        prod = (s[:, None] * prod[None, :]).ravel()
    return prod

# -------- Testing Correctness and Time Measuring --------
    
tb = time.time()    
a0 = BlockValCalcRef(Set1S, Set2S, Set3S, Set12A, Set23A, Set13A),
t0 = time.time() - tb
print(f'base time {round(t0, 4)} sec')

tb = time.time()    
a1 = BlockVolCalc(Set1S, Set2S, Set3S, Set12A, Set23A, Set13A)
t1 = time.time() - tb
print(f'improved time {round(t1, 4)} sec, speedup {round(t0 / t1, 2)}x')

tb = time.time()    
a2 = BlockVolCalc2(Set1S, Set2S, Set3S, Set12A, Set23A, Set13A)
t2 = time.time() - tb
print(f'improved2 time {round(t2, 4)} sec, speedup {round(t0 / t2, 2)}x')
    
assert np.allclose(a0, a1)
assert np.allclose(a0, a2)
```

Output:

```
base time 2.7569 sec
improved time 0.0015 sec, speedup 1834.83x
improved2 time 0.001 sec, speedup 2755.09x
```

My function embedded into your initial first code will look like [here in this code](https://tio.run/##pVM9b8IwEN39K07qEAedUB1DP5A6tN27IHVBGUxiRISxU9uhSv88dWIoqcpSyODzPd1773yn1K1fG833@@RVqKJRwhubkGpbG@tBN9u6BeFA12QuPZvDU7iOhbWipQuGGXKc4BTv8D5P4QYf8BHZLTKGLEPGkU2QTfO042ZXcPkVXJY9X9E0v4LMLiaTUq7gRZli825Ut5aM9tNH6AfZBx5DeF5EeYzBNJ0RCN8ZxqGdpYtyKQ7S7HfK5@mPyl@Lk1AIrtI0lqUniRMeaGfxrtPoUVtTRkWjpaOUYagvfVvLiK6UEZ5nsXhlLDioNFi5k9bJki7@MZv8MJyBLXWLGcJbsM5h1IOLLkGY5enYip1UNDpb6Rur@wpCjtsJApcvipBkK3RVd3@dBL@WwcM1yoOqnAcBhWlqJeFTtC4ZOoaZFEvr6RFKz7UzYhlJPpqq2ECxluH0Blz1JcGsDjau90mIknogtd9/Aw).

Also I created [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/)-based variant of code, which will use all of your CPU cores and GPU, this code needs installing tensorflow one time by `python -m pip install --upgrade numpy tensorflow`:

```
import numpy as np

N = 18
Set1S, Set2S, Set3S, Set12A, Set23A, Set13A = [np.arange(1 + i, N + 1 + i) for i in range(6)]
dtype = np.float32

def Prepare(Set1S, Set2S, Set3S, Set12A, Set23A, Set13A):
    import numpy as np
    Set12A, Set23A, Set13A = np.sin(Set12A), np.sin(Set23A), np.sin(Set13A)
    return [np.abs(s).astype(dtype) for s in [Set1S, Set2S, Set3S, Set12A, Set23A, Set13A]]
    
sets = Prepare(Set1S, Set2S, Set3S, Set12A, Set23A, Set13A)

def ProcessNP(sets):
    import numpy as np
    res = np.ones((1,), dtype = dtype)
    for s in reversed(sets):
        res = (s[:, None] * res[None, :]).ravel()
    res = np.cbrt(res) * 12
    return res

def ProcessTF(sets, *, state = {}):
    if 'graph' not in state:
        import os
        os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
        import numpy as np, tensorflow as tf
        tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
        cpus = tf.config.list_logical_devices('CPU')
        #print(f"CPUs: {[e.name for e in cpus]}")
        gpus = tf.config.list_logical_devices('GPU')
        #print(f"GPUs: {[e.name for e in gpus]}")
        print(f"GPU: {len(gpus) > 0}")
        state['graph'] = tf.Graph()
        state['sess'] = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph = state['graph'])
        #tf.device(cpus[0].name if len(gpus) == 0 else gpus[0].name)
        with state['sess'].as_default(), state['graph'].as_default():
            res = tf.ones((1,), dtype = dtype)
            state['inp'] = []
            for s in reversed(sets):
                sph = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype, s.shape)
                state['inp'].insert(0, sph)
                res = sph[:, None] * res[None, :]
                res = tf.reshape(res, (tf.size(res),))
            res = tf.math.pow(res, 1 / 3) * 12
            state['out'] = res
        def Run(sets):
            with state['sess'].as_default(), state['graph'].as_default():
                return tf.compat.v1.get_default_session().run(
                    state['out'], {ph: s for ph, s in zip(state['inp'], sets)}
                )
        state['run'] = Run

    return state['run'](sets)

# ------------ Testing ------------

npa, tfa = ProcessNP(sets), ProcessTF(sets)
assert np.allclose(npa, tfa)

from timeit import timeit

print('Nums:', round(npa.size / 10 ** 6, 3), 'M')
timeit_num = 2
print('NP:', round(timeit(lambda: ProcessNP(sets), number = timeit_num) / timeit_num, 3), 'sec')
print('TF:', round(timeit(lambda: ProcessTF(sets), number = timeit_num) / timeit_num, 3), 'sec')
```

On my 2-cores CPU it prints:

```
GPU: False
Nums: 34.012 M
NP: 3.487 sec
TF: 1.185 sec
```

Comment: Wow, that was a fast response.  I'm still picking through your code to make sure I understand it all.  So, it looks like I can remove BlockValCalcRef and just leave in BlockVolCalc, yes?

Pardon my ignorance, but what is the name of the resulting list from BlockVolCalc?

I may be able to get access to some cloud computing resources, if that would help overcome the RAM issues.  My testing desktop PC has 128 GB of RAM, so I'll test on that first.   Speeding it up even more than what you already did is amazing, so I'll have to check if I overtax my system with the current method

Comment: @JCombs I've just posted second twice more faster solution according to idea posted in my answer.

Comment: @JCombs Now algorithm is probably the fastest possible if not to count possibilities to parallelize on multi-core CPU or to use GPU, or even to use multiple computers.

Comment: @JCombs You just copy code of `BlockVolCalc2()` function and use it, nothing else needed. Look at your very first code in your question, line `arr = np.array(BlockVol)`,  so all functions in my code produce exactly this resulting `arr`, after that you'll need to do your extra operations `BlockVol = np.cbrt(BlockVol)` and `BlockVol = BlockVol * 12`.

Comment: Wow, thanks again.  I'll update again once I do some testing, but I think that multi-core CPU or GPU is definitely an option in the future.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here, since I keep getting an error with BlockVol not defined when I try to do anything involving BlockVol after running your code

Comment: @JCombs Yes, this kind of just pure 6-sets cross-product can be very easily parallelized on multi-core, or multi-gpu, or multi-computers, or network cluster of computers. So in the future this improvement can be done if needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223885/discussion-between-arty-and-jcombs).

Comment: @JCombs I'm writing all my thoughts to [this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223885/discussion-between-arty-and-jcombs) mentioned by link above. I don't see you there, you left the room. Please look there from time to time if we want to continue solving task for multi-core/multi-gpu/multi-computers/multi-cluster cases.

Comment: @JCombs I see you have now enough reputation for UpVoting. If you like my answer and if it answers your question you can UpVote and Accept it. To do this go to the top of my answer and there is to the left from it is Checkmark to accept and Up-Arrow for Up-Voting.